# when I select an option of a select I want the others to have an empty value

Tags: javascript, html

as already mentioned, when I select an option of a select I want the others to have an empty value if one is already selected, i.e. I want the others to have a value="" (therefore that it be emptied"

this is my code:

```js
let selects = document.querySelectorAll('.selectes')
selects.forEach(sel =>
    sel.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        if (e.target.id != sel.getAttribute('id')) {
            sel.value = '';
        }
    })

)
```

```html
 <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
    <select name="cars" id="cars" class="selectes">
        <option value="">Value Empty</option>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>

    <label for="cars">Choose a cycle:</label>
    <select name="cars" id="cycles" class="selectes">
        <option value="">Value Empty</option>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>

    <label for="cars">Choose a bike:</label>
    <select name="cars" id="bikes" class="selectes">
        <option value="">Value Empty</option>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: What happens then if the user later chooses a different option? It now has no value.

Comment: I want to allow only one value to be selected for a select, as if the others were disabled (but I only make the value empty)

Comment: `if (e.target.id != sel.getAttribute('id'))` this won't work because e.target === sel.

Comment: @James How can I modify the code to make it work?

Comment: Maybe something like [enable or disable option from select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973236) (but disabling all options)?

Comment: By default, only one value can be selected unless you use the `multiple` attribute` But if you remove the options when they select one, they won't be able to change their mind since the other options' values will be blank.

Answer (score 1):

Get all the `select` elements, add listener to each select element by looping over them. So whenever a select change, loop through all other `select` elements and set their values into *"Value Empty"*.

```js
const selects = document.querySelectorAll('.selectes');
selects.forEach(function(select) {
  select.addEventListener('change', function() {
    selects.forEach(function(s) {
      if (s !== select) {
        s.value = '';
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
<select name="cars" id="cars" class="selectes">
  <option value="">Value Empty</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<label for="cars">Choose a cycle:</label>
<select name="cars" id="cycles" class="selectes">
  <option value="">Value Empty</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<label for="cars">Choose a bike:</label>
<select name="cars" id="bikes" class="selectes">
  <option value="">Value Empty</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through all the selects within the listener, and reset the ones that aren't the one that was just changed.

```js
let selects = document.querySelectorAll('.selectes')
selects.forEach(sel =>
    sel.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        // sel was changed, so reset all the other selects which are not sel.
        selects.forEach(s => {
          if (s !== sel) 
            s.value = '';
        });
    })
)
```

```html
<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
    <select name="cars" id="cars" class="selectes">
        <option value="">Value Empty</option>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>

    <label for="cars">Choose a cycle:</label>
    <select name="cars" id="cycles" class="selectes">
        <option value="">Value Empty</option>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>

    <label for="cars">Choose a bike:</label>
    <select name="cars" id="bikes" class="selectes">
        <option value="">Value Empty</option>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do that this way ?

First of all, the `forEach()` method accepts up to 3 arguments: [link on the doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#callbackfn)

- `sel`  -> the current element
- `i`    -> current element list index
- `All`  -> a return on the entire processed list

Like any selection made on a list, this acts on the `selectedIndex` property;
this code here uses this property exclusively.

as any change to one of the `select`s implies an update of the other `select`s, they must be reset their `selectedIndex` to zero in an internal loop of the `All` argument, this time with `x` as loop index.

if `x===i`, then we are on the same element, it is therefore excluded to reset its selectedIndex property to zero.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.selectes')
  .forEach( (sel, i, all) =>
  {
  sel.addEventListener('change', e => 
    {
    if (sel.selectedIndex > 0)
      all.forEach( (xSel,x) =>  { if (x!==i) xSel.selectedIndex = 0; })
    })
  });
```

```css
label {
  display : inline-block;
  width   : 10em;
  }
label > select {
  display : block;
  }
```

```html
<label>
  Choose a car:
  <select id="cars" class="selectes">
    <option value=""         > Value Empty </option>
    <option value="volvo"    > Volvo       </option>
    <option value="saab"     > Saab        </option>
    <option value="mercedes" > Mercedes    </option>
    <option value="audi"     > Audi        </option>
  </select>
</label>
<label>
  Choose a cycle:
  <select id="cycles" class="selectes">
    <option value=""         > Value Empty </option>
    <option value="volvo"    > Volvo       </option>
    <option value="saab"     > Saab        </option>
    <option value="mercedes" > Mercedes    </option>
    <option value="audi"     > Audi        </option>
  </select>
</label>
<label>
  Choose a bike:
  <select id="bikes" class="selectes">
    <option value=""         > Value Empty </option>
    <option value="volvo"    > Volvo       </option>
    <option value="saab"     > Saab        </option>
    <option value="mercedes" > Mercedes    </option>
    <option value="audi"     > Audi        </option>
  </select>
</label>
```

Comment: If you could add some description would be more clear!

Comment: @XM01-standswithPalestine  Could do have some respect to my programming style ? (inspired by Whitesmiths)

Comment: @XM01-standswithPalestine , my post is updated.

Comment: And sorry I didn't mean to mess with your programming style (inspired by Whitesmiths); I just want to make it clear to other developers! But since you are the owner of code, feel free to choose your style preferred!

Comment: @XM01-standswithPalestine I do a lot of code maintenance and I can assure you that the K&R code is a disaster that should be made to disappear. It was never used by Kernighan or Ritchie, but by their publisher simply to save paper.